# How dangerous is to use tx.origin to check if msg.sender is some address? (details below...)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, security, selfdestruct

Let's say:

```
function transfer() public payable
 { 

 require(tx.origin == 0xb2930B35844a230f00E51431aCAe96Fe543a0347);  
msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)();

}
```

Ignore the address above I just copied it from etherscan it belongs to some mining pool...so the question is: how can this address get "spoofed" if at all? Isn't tx.origin more secure since the caller can never be contract? Thanx!

Comment: I'd say tx.origin cannot be "spoofed" in the usual sense. But if you call a malicious contract M it can call a "victim" contract V. If V only verifies tx.origin it will think it was called by you. There was a famous multisig wallet that was exploitable that way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your question title. You obviously can't use `tx.origin` to check whether `msg.sender` is some address, because they have different meanings. If you want to check `msg.sender`, you should check `msg.sender`.

'More secure' does not exist in the space of smart contracts. They either do what they're supposed to do, or they don't.

- `msg.sender` is the address that called your contract. It can be either a human address (controlled by a private key) or a contract address.
- `tx.origin` is the address that submitted the current transaction. It is never a contract address.

The fact that `tx.origin` is present in your contract does not mean it can't be called by another contract.

```
if (tx.origin != msg.sender)
{
    // This contract was called by another contract.
    // Therefore, msg.sender and tx.origin have different values:
    // - msg.sender is the other contract
    // - tx.origin is the original 'human' address that submitted the current transaction
}
```

`msg.sender` and `tx.origin` are not more or less secure than one another. They simply have a different meaning. I can tell you though, in almost 3 years of contract development I have never encountered a single use-case for `tx.origin`. You should use `msg.sender`.

Comment: Thanks but what about the example I gave? Is this "hackable"? I googled this: https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tx-origin-attacks-58211ad95514 - so this seems hackable but here tx.origin is owner and not any address? My question is: can any address be spoofed even the zero 0x0 or so? I guess not maybe still can't grasp the whole logic, should have a look at the sample in the link...

Comment: @RobertGgg `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` can never be `0x0`. I don't know what your contract is supposed to do. The way you have written it now, any contract called by `0xb2930B...` can take amounts of 1 ether from your contract. So yes, it's probably hackable. If you just use `msg.sender` instead of `tx.origin`, only `0xb2930B...` will be able to take the 1 ether.

Comment: I see, I will try to replicate the example from the link...one more thing: it uses transfer and not call so maybe using "transfer" can save the day given the 2300 limitation of gas? As far as I know since Istanbul 2 days ago, transfer can send over 2300 gas and thus allow such things? will have to test on ropsten and see...

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception about `tx.origin` being "insecure" or "unsafe" and that you should not use it. But this is not exactly the case.

There is inherently nothing wrong with `tx.origin`, it does exactly what it says it does, provide you the address of the original transaction sender.

How you decide to use it, hence how "dangerous" it is, is less of a Solidity issue and more of a common sense issue.

From your provided example:

```
function transfer() public payable{ 
    require(tx.origin == 0xb2930B35844a230f00E51431aCAe96Fe543a0347);
    msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)();
}
```

This is the same as a real life example of writing a bank cheque:

1. the signature signed by `0xb2930B35844a230f00E51431aCAe96Fe543a0347`
2. requesting access to the bank account funds under "this contract address"
3. amount is 1 ether
4. pay to `person holding this cheque`

In this case, there is no guarantee who is the person holding the cheque.
It is up to you, the developer implementing the bank policies to decide if you want to allow this cheque to go through.